# Can the function of the iTunes shuffle control be changed in iTunes 11?

Tags: itunes

I just updated my iTunes to 11.0. I just want to know how I can make the songs in my playlists in shuffle mode, but not the songs in my Library. Before with iTunes 10, you can have that option where you only shuffle songs in your playlists but not the library. But with iTunes 11, I can't seem to find that option. When I have songs in my playlists in shuffle mode, it also shuffles the songs I play from my Library.

So, can shuffle only affect a playlist and remain unset for general library play?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Not through the GUI anyway...

Answer (score 3):

There is a [image] shuffle button right beside the playlist name (at the top), when you have a playlist selected

In the above, my sidebar is *off*, (so I get this bar)

`Songs   Albums   Artists   Genres   Playlists   Radio   Match        iTunes Store`

but this also works if a playlist is selected and the sidebar is on.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to Controls > Shuffle > Turn On Shuffle and play a song.

[image: Screenshot of the above answer]

Comment: By turning on Shuffle, that just shuffle the entire library plus songs in the playlists. If you disable the shuffle button in the playlists, it also disables the shuffle button in the Library. I just want to figure out how to have the shuffle mode on independently for certain playlists and Library. With iTunes 10, there was that option.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the menu bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, then navigate to Controls > Shuffle > Turn On Shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to turn shuffle on/off for independent playlists - it's either on for everything or off for everything - which is a hassle. In 10 it was easy to toggle back and forth between a shuffling playlist and a fixed playlist - something important if you need to use more than one playlist at the same time..

Comment: Please don't use answers to ask new questions.